# How to Import local text file to populate drop downs with FileReader()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of stuck on a problem, I’m trying to import a text file from my local computer to JavaScript and populate HTML drop down's according to the text file. I have spent a lot of time looking at similar questions on stack overflow and i haven't found the solution to the problem yet. Here is an example of what the text file looks like:

```
 Dogs - 
 Blue Dog
 Black Doggo
 Random Doggo

 Cats -
 Neon cat
 Grumpy cat
 Potato cat
```

Here is what my JS looks like:

```
    function LoadTxtFile(p) {
        var AllTxtdata = '';

        var FileRead = new FileReader();
        FileRead.onload = function (e) {
            if (FileRead.readyState === 2) {

                AllTxtdata = FileRead;
                var lines = FileRead.result.split('\n').map(function (line) {
                    return line.trim();
                });

                var select = $("select[name=MySelect]");
                var optionCounter = 0;
                var currentGroup = "";
                lines.forEach(function (line) {

                    if (line.endsWith(" -")) {
                        currentGroup = line.substring(0, line.length - 2);
                        optionCounter = 0;
                        select.append("<optgroup id'" + currentGroup + "' label='" + currentGroup + "'>");
                    } else if (line === "") {
                        select.append("</optgroup>");
                    } else {
                        select.append("<option type='checkbox' id='" + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' name'"
                            + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' value='"
                            + line + "'>" + line + "</option>");
                    }

                });
            };
        }


    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="Bark">

    <input type="file" id="file" />
     </div>
```

i'm trying to populate HTML dropdown select "MySelect" with an option group and options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing couple of things in your code.

- Attach the event to the file control.
- Read the actual file from within the function.

Here, I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/piyushksingh11/L5dagya0/) using your own code. Below, I am only highlighting the lines of code that, I have added there. Rest of the code is same.

Get the target file first, inside LoadTxtFile().

```
var targetFile = p.target.files[0];
```

Once, it's established, that there are files, start reading the file in the last line.

```
FileRead.readAsText(targetFile);
```

Finally, outside the method declaration, attach the event to the file control.

```
document.getElementById('myFile').addEventListener('change', LoadTxtFile, false);
```

Comment: Getting an error saying line in undefined, any ideas?

Comment: line is the object used inside your foreach loop. It can't be accessed from outside. Are you getting this error in the same code??